# No run time & compile time error in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute the following small script.

**test.pl**

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
$value = 1;
```

The output is

```
perl -c test.pl
test.pl syntax OK
```

Please let me know why it is not throwing error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour. I'm getting `Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name`.

Comment: @choroba:  I'm not receive any error while compiling this.

Comment: I am also getting error :  `Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 3.
test.pl had compilation errors.`

Comment: Please provide the output of `perl -v | grep "This is" ; perl -le'use strict; print $INC{"strict.pm"}' ; perl  -e'use strict; $value = 1;' ; od -c test.pl`

Comment: (When do you, please post a comment that includes `@ikegami` so I get notified.)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Perl are you using? This is Perl 5.18:

```
$ cat test1.pl 
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
$value = 1;

$ perl -c test1.pl
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at test1.pl line 3.
test1.pl had compilation errors.
```

I get the error.

Is it possible you're not running against the Perl script you think you are?